# Как вывести две переменные в PrintIn()?

Tags: java

Как в функции PrintIn вывести на экран сразу две переменные(к примеру переменную a и переменную b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.out.println( a.toString() + b.toString );

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогло.

Comment: Не забудьте отметить как ответ :-)

Comment: Я уже отметил.

Comment: @Лого Нужно кликнуть по галочке под кулачком, тогда вопрос станет принятым (зеленым) в поиске.

Comment: Не-а, там есть кнопочка под руками отметить как правильный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println( a + "" + b);

Да вздравствует автоматическое преобразование типов :)
чтобы пользоваться этой фичей с другими обьектами нужно переопределить метод toString()

Comment: не обязательно, он выведет toString() который класса Object =)

Comment: если для объекта функция toString() переопределена, то будетвызываться именно она, а не класса Object

Comment: Этот вариант менее эффективен, чем тот, что выше, так как выполняется лишний вызов StringBuilder.append.

Comment: если идет мордобой за перфоманс тогда уже так

    System.out.println(a.toString().concat(b.toString()));

или, если трактовать "сразу 2 переменных" как "2 пременных в одной строке"

    System.out.print(a);
    System.out.println(b);